# nodejs express reuse a route get method in another file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In file groups.js, I have the following route:

```
router.get('/status', function(req, res, next) {
    // some data
    return res.status(200).json(someData);
}
module.exports = router;
```

and in file users.js, i have the following route:

```
router.get('/create', function(req, res, next) {

    // re-use the groups route '/status' here and get 'someData'
    // do some stuff with 'someData'
    // do more bunch of data

    return res.status(200).json(bunchOfData);
}
```

how can I use the `status` get route from file groups in the users file?

Comment: Extract the common functionality and create a common utility function, import it when needed and call in both routes?

Comment: @Li357 how do i export it given that i am already exporting the router and it is being used in the app... how not to affect the curret setup?

Comment: What do you mean? Create a new file with the common function. Then import that file in `users.js` and `groups.js` and use the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just put it into an external module which you then import it using require:

**Route1:**

```
router.get('/status', function(req, res, next) {
    // some data
    return res.status(200).json(someData);
}
module.exports = router;
```

**Route2:**

```
router.get('/create', function(req, res, next) {

    // re-use the groups route '/status' here and get 'someData'
    // do some stuff with 'someData'
    // do more bunch of data

    return res.status(200).json(bunchOfData);
}
```

**Utility.js**

```
let status;
// status = whatever you need it to be
module.exports = status;
```

Now import the utility in both route1 and route2 and then you have access to the same status variable in the different modules.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, Use `npm request module` to hit your own route/api:
Install by `npm install request --save` command

Require it:
`const request = require('request');`

```
router.get('/create', function(req, res, next) {

        // re-use the groups route '/status' here and get 'someData'
        // do some stuff with 'someData'
        // do more bunch of data

        //for local use: http://localhost:<port of server>/status?<query string>            
        request('http://<host>:<port>/status?<query string>', function (error, response, body) {

            console.log('error:', error); // Print the error if one occurred
            console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode); // Print the response status code if a response was received
            console.log('body:', body); // Print the HTML for the Google homepage.

             return res.status(200).json(body);
        });
    }
```